# Injecting JVM params into spring property files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

In short - is there a way to set the value of spring properties to what's been set as a JVM arg? E.g. I have a netflix turbine cluster which needs the following property set:

`turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=myCluster`

Is it possible to a way of setting a JVM param as

`-DturbineCluster=myCluster`

and then in the property file setting:

`turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=${turbineCluster}`

I did actually try this and it didn't work.  Can this be done from a property file or does this kind of thing need to be done programatically?

(Apologies if this has been asked before - had a quick search and couldn't find anything.)

Comment: Is this spring boot?

Comment: yes, it is spring boot

Comment: That should actually work. You are letting Spring Boot load the properties and you haven't added your own `@PropertySource` for loading the property file? Instead of passing it as JVM param you could try passing it as a program argument `--turbineCluster=myCluster` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in spring boot, it may be supported by spring as well

-Dspring.application.json='{"turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig":"myCluster"}'

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html